# Inline version of a for loop with `.add` or `.append`

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, inline

Is there a clean inline way to define a `for` loop that has `.add` or `.append`? For example, consider the following `for` loop:

```
import collections

s = [('red', 1), ('blue', 2), ('red', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1), ('blue', 4)]
d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k, v in s:
  d[k].add(v)
```

I can think of writing it inline like the following code, but it doesn't look clean:

```
_ = [d[k].add(v) for k, v in s]
```

Is there a better way, for example, using `itertools.accumualte`? Something like

```
d = ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making it "inline"? Using an explicit `for` loop is fine. If you're doing it often, put it in a function (or use a library; in this case, look for "multi dict" or "bag").

Comment: I think, your code is clean enough :) Actually, it is pretty clean.

Comment: I'm normally a big advocate of itertools myself, and even I agree that the code you have is probably the cleanest way to do it. Hold onto that instinct, because it's nice to have, but I don't think it applies in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think your first way is very clean and better than this answer but here is a **one-line solution**:

```
import itertools

...    

d = {k: set(v for _, v in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(s), lambda x: x[0])}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'blue': {2, 4}, 'red': {1, 3}}
```

**Another approach** (not one-line):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(set)

def change_dict(k, v):
    d[k].add(v)

list(itertools.starmap(change_dict, s)) # list is to call iterator
print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'red': {1, 3}, 'blue': {2, 4}})
```

Comment: This is nice, but it requires sorting which is not optimal for speed.

Comment: @user2725109 Yes, unfortunately, it requires sorting first. Btw, just added another approach. It is not one-line but it may lead you somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Using `itertools.accumulate`. May not be efficient but solves the problem.

```
d = itertools.accumulate(
    s,
    lambda d, kv: dict(d, **{kv[0]: d.get(kv[0], set()).union({kv[1]})}),
    initial=dict())
d = list(d)[-1]
```